# Error(): The constructor File(URL) is undefined

Tags: java, file-io

I want to load sheet.xlsx into a variable by using the File() construtctor.

Please find my code snippet below:

```
public class Main {
    
    File input = new File(Main.class.getResource("/res/sheet.xlsx"));

}
```

The sheet file is in a resources folder, under the root project, and checked the "use as source folder" option in eclipse.

The File() constructor is returning the following error
`The constructor File(URL) is undefined` even though the `getResource()` returns an URL.

Am I using a wrong approach? Is there a better approach for my problem.

Your inputs helps!

Comment: It says that class `File` doesn't have a `File(URL)` constructor, which is correct. See the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#constructor.summary).

Comment: *FYI:* If the application gets deployed as a Jar file, the resource file will not be a file on the file system, which means that what you're trying to do won't work. Don't use `File` to access resources. To read a resource, use `InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/sheet.xlsx")`

Comment: `File` variables don't have content. They are just placeholders for filenames. Resources are not files. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is fundamentally not possible. A `java.io.File` object represents, quite literally, a **file** and is *incapable* of representing anything else. It cannot represent 'a sack of bytes', or 'an entry in a jar'. And yet that's what you have here (an entry in a jar). The File API is aware of this and doesn't let you make a File object based on a URL, as that usually is impossible.

On the other hand, resources are loaded by the classloader. Out of the box, that means it can load either files or entries in jar files, and if you have custom classloaders, sky is the limit: load from the web, load from a database, generate on the fly - whatever you want.

The fix is to **not use file** - what you have just isn't one, so don't try to represent it with one. Fortunately, all non-idiotic APIs have solutions for this; there will be a method that takes an `InputStream` or `URL` in addition to whatever you have that needs a `File`. If your API doesn't offer such a thing, find a better library. But, most likely, it does.

Bad idea:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("res/sheet.xlsx");
someApi.load(fis);
```

good idea:

```
try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/sheet.xlsx")) {
    someApi.load(in);
}
```